# SQLAlchemy declarative dataclass mapping: How to create non-required columns?

Tags: python, sqlalchemy, orm, default-value, python-dataclasses

I am trying to figure out how to use declarative mapping with dataclasses in SQLAlchemy.

Setup:

```
from dotenv import load_dotenv
import os
from sqlalchemy.engine import URL

#test abc

load_dotenv()

url_object = URL.create(
    "postgresql+psycopg2",
    username=os.environ.get('DBUSER'),
    password=os.environ.get('DBPASS'),  # plain (unescaped) text
    host=os.environ.get('DBIP'),
    database=os.environ.get('DBNAME'),
    port=os.environ.get('DBPORT')
)

from sqlalchemy import create_engine, Table, Column, ForeignKey, Integer, String, Boolean


engine = create_engine(url_object,
                       echo=True)




from typing_extensions import Annotated
from typing import List
from typing import Optional
from sqlalchemy import ForeignKey
from sqlalchemy import String
from sqlalchemy.orm import DeclarativeBase
from sqlalchemy.orm import Mapped
from sqlalchemy.orm import MappedAsDataclass
from sqlalchemy.orm import mapped_column
from sqlalchemy.orm import relationship

from sqlalchemy.orm import registry
reg = registry()


class Base(MappedAsDataclass, DeclarativeBase):
    """subclasses will be converted to dataclasses"""
```

I can make a simple mapped class and associated table like this:

```
class Test(Base):
    __tablename__ = 'test'
    id: Mapped[int] = mapped_column(init=False, primary_key=True)
    intVar: Mapped[int]
    strVar: Mapped[str]

Test.__table__

Base.metadata.create_all(engine)
```

The table is created as expected, with columns for 'id', 'intVar', and 'strVar'

However, when I try to create variables with defaults, those columns are not created, my table only has the first four. When I look at the table test2, I only see the first four columns, not the last three. All of the variables whose columns were not created have default values:

```
import datetime

class Test2(Base):
    __tablename__ = 'test2'
    id: Mapped[int] = mapped_column(init=False, primary_key=True)
    intVar: Mapped[int]
    strVar: Mapped[str]
    anotherVar: Mapped[str]
    optVar: Mapped[Optional[str]] = ''
    yaVAR: Mapped[str] = ''
    date: Mapped[datetime.datetime] = datetime.datetime.now()

Test2.__table__

Base.metadata.create_all(engine)
```

However, as far as I can tell, I need default values for variables that are optional, otherwise if I try to create an instance of the class without the "optional" variable, it complains about missing positional arguments:

```
import datetime

class Test3(Base):
    __tablename__ = 'test3'
    id: Mapped[int] = mapped_column(init=False, primary_key=True)
    intVar: Mapped[int]
    strVar: Mapped[str]
    anotherVar: Mapped[str]
    optVar: Mapped[Optional[str]]
    yaVAR: Mapped[str]
    date: Mapped[datetime.datetime] = datetime.datetime.now()

Test3.__table__

Base.metadata.create_all(engine)


t3 = Test3(intVar = 0, strVar = 'abc', anotherVar = 'xyz', optVar = "bs", yaVAR='morebs', date = datetime.datetime.now())

t4 = Test3(intVar = 0, strVar = 'abc', anotherVar = 'xyz', yaVAR='morebs', date = datetime.datetime.now())


t4 = Test3(intVar = 0, strVar = 'abc', anotherVar = 'xyz', yaVAR='morebs', date = datetime.datetime.now())
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
TypeError: __init__() missing 1 required positional argument: 'optVar'
```

#### So how do I make a dataclass with optional variables and have the columns get created when the table is created?

Answer (score 1):

Ok, so I had misunderstood how to create the optional variables. All worked as intended when I used `mapped_column(default=None)` instead of `Mapped[Optional[]]`.

```
class Error(Base):
    __tablename__ = 'errors'
    id: Mapped[int] = mapped_column(init=False, primary_key=True)
    feed_id: Mapped[int]
    url: Mapped[str]
    error: Mapped[str]
    step: Mapped[str]
    host: Mapped[str]
    parameters: Mapped[Optional[str]] = mapped_column(default=None)
    uagent: Mapped[Optional[str]] = mapped_column(default=None)
    proxy: Mapped[Optional[str]] = mapped_column(default=None)
    status_code: Mapped[Optional[int]] = mapped_column(default=None)
    date: Mapped[datetime.datetime] = mapped_column(default=None)
```